# Linearly Independent Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I recently proved the following:

> If $R(T) \cap R(U) = \{0\}$, where $T$ and $U$ are nonzero linear operators, then $T$ and $U$ are linearly independent in $\cal{L}$$(V,W)$, where $\cal{L}$$(V,W)$ is the vector space of all linear operators from $V$ to $W$.

I am wondering if the following is a counterexample to the converse. Let $I$ be the identity matrix on $\Bbb{C}^2$ and let $A$ be the matrix with $1$'s along the diagonal and $2$ in each off-diagonal entry. Clearly they are linearly independent, and since they are both invertible, $R(I) = \Bbb{C}^2 = R(A)$, which means their ranges most certainly intersect in a nontrivial way.

---

I have a related question which I don't think merits opening another thread (if not, please forgive me).

Let $F$ be some field, and $F^{\Bbb{N}}$ denote the vector space of infinite tuples (i.e., sequences in $F$). I am trying to show that the left-shift (denoted by $L$) and right-shift (denoted by $R$) operators are linearly independent. Here is my proof.

Let $c_1, c_2 \in F$, and suppose that $c_1 L + c_2 R = 0$, or that $(c_1 L + c_2 R)(x) = 0$ or $c_1L(x) + c_2 R(x) = 0$ for all $x \in F^{\Bbb{N}}$.  Let $x = (0,1,0,1,0,0,...)$. Then

$$0 = c_1L(0,1,0,1,0,0,...) + c_2 R(0,1,0,1,0,0,...)$$

$$= c_1 (1,0,1,0,0,...) + c_2(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,...),$$

which implies $c_1 = 0$ and $c_1 + c_2 = 0$ and therefore $c_2 = 0$. Hence, these two operators are linearly independent.

Does this sound right? I wonder, what does the span of these two operators look like? Anything interesting? What sort of inner products can we endow $\mathcal{L}(F^{\Bbb{N}})$ with; would $L$ and $R$ be orthogonal with respect to this inner product?

Comment: About the first question. Invertible matrices are onto and so they do have the same range. So yes you are right. The second proof is also right. I don't think that the span of this two operators is very interesting. There is a natural norm on this space - the operator norm. I don't know about an inner product on such spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Define $T$ on $\mathbb R^2$ by $T(1,0)=(1,0),T(0,1)=(0,1)$ and $U$ by $U(1,0)=(1,0),U(0,1)=(0,0)$,these transformations satisfy $R(T)\cap R(U)\neq\{0\}$,but they are still linearly independent.